# How to compose functions with compatible parmeter / result types in Kotlin?

Tags: functional-programming, kotlin

I have an `interface` which looks like this:

```
interface FontRegionTransformer<R> {

    fun transform(region: R, textCharacter: TextCharacter): R
}
```

I'm not an expert in category theory but [as I have learned previously](http://rea.tech/how-we-used-category-theory-to-solve-a-problem-in-java/) this structure is a monoid *(is it?)* and I can combine any number of functions which take `R` and return `R` together.

This is what I have right now:

```
var image = source.getSubimage(meta.x * width, meta.y * height, width, height)
regionTransformers.forEach {
    image = it.transform(image, textCharacter)
}
```

This works but I have a question: how do I combine a `List` of `FontRegionTransformer`s to a single function? Can I do it without adding a `compose` function to my interface? I tried it with `reduce` but it did not click.

**Clarification:** What I'd like to achieve is to combine the functions stored in `regionTransformers` into a single function so instead of the loop here:

```
var image = source.getSubimage(meta.x * width, meta.y * height, width, height)
regionTransformers.forEach {
    image = it.transform(image, textCharacter)
}
```

I'd like to have something like this:

```
var image = source.getSubimage(meta.x * width, meta.y * height, width, height)
return combinedTransformers.invoke(image)
```

Comment: What do you mean by "Combine a `List` of `FontRegionTransformer`s to a single function"? Could you please specify what your expected input and output is?

Comment: I edited my question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For the composition definition, it is not quite clear, when the composed transformer is called, what `textCharacter` the second `FontRegionTransformer<R>` should get. Here, I assume that it is the same `textCharacter` that is passed into the call, and which is naturally passed to the first transformer.

You can implement the custom composition operation as an extension for `FontRegionTransformer<R>`:

```
fun <R> FontRegionTransformer<R>.compose(other: FontRegionTransformer<R>) =
    object : FontRegionTransformer<R> {
        override fun transform(region: R, textCharacter: TextCharacter): R {
            val firstResult = this@compose.transform(region, textCharacter)
            return other.transform(firstResult, textCharacter)
        }
    }
```

<sup>You can add the [`infix` modifier](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/functions.html#infix-notation) to `compose` to use the infix notation `a compose b`, or make it [overload an operator `+` or `*`](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/operator-overloading.html#operator-overloading), if you like to call it as `a * b`. Or use a non-extension top-level function for `compose(a, b)` calls.</sup>

Then you can compose two `FontRegionTransformer`s:

```
val composed = first.compose(second)
```

And to compose a list of transformers into one, use [`reduce`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/reduce.html):

```
val transformers: List<FontRegionTransformer<SomeType>> = TODO()

val composition = transformers.reduce { a, b -> a.compose(b) }
```

For `FontRegionTransformer<R>` to be monoid, the composition operation should be associative (`a ∘ (b ∘ c)` should be equivalent to `(a ∘ b) ∘ c` for all `a`, `b` and `c`) and the above implementation seems to satisfy this requirement. But, strictly speaking, it should also have a neutral element, such `n` that `a ∘ n = n ∘ a = a` for any `a`. These two requirements cannot be expressed in terms of the Kotlin type system and should instead be a part of the contract.

---

A one-statement solution is, inlining `compose` into the `reduce` call:

```
val composition = transformers.reduce { a, b ->
    object : FontRegionTransformer<SomeType> {
        override fun transform(region: SomeType, textCharacter: TextCharacter) =
            a.transform(region, textCharacter).let { b.transform(it, textCharacter) }
    }
}
```

Comment: So I can't compose them without adding a `compose` function? Can't I use `reduce` or some other mapping function to achieve this?

Comment: @AdamArold, since it is a custom interface, you need a custom function to operate with its instances. :) A library function would not know what to do with `textCharacter` anyway. Even for the built-in function types like `(T) -> R`, there's no built-in composition in `kotlin-stdlib`, but one can use a third-party functional programming libraries like [funKTionale](https://github.com/MarioAriasC/funKTionale).

Comment: And by the way, with the custom `compose` function, `reduce` is exactly what you do next. :)

Comment: @AdamArold, I've added a one-statement solution if you don't like a separate `compose` function, though IMHO it is less readable.